# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e while deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I'm encountering this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e after a successful deployment to Heroku

I'm using angular social share btw: https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare

removing the `run` function and module name `djds4rce.angular-socialshare` do not cause error but I badly need that for Fb sharing.

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./angular

MyApp = angular.module( "MyApp", ["ui.router", "ngCsv", "ui.bootstrap", "ngResource", "templates", "angularFileUpload", "ngSanitize", "ngCookies", "textAngular", "djds4rce.angular-socialshare"] ).run(function($FB){
  $FB.init('1438666983087556');
});
```

Any idea(s)? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails minifies the js, so you have to use a different syntax:

```
MyApp = angular.module( "MyApp", ["ui.router", "ngCsv", "ui.bootstrap", "ngResource", "templates", "angularFileUpload", "ngSanitize", "ngCookies", "textAngular", "djds4rce.angular-socialshare"] );

MyApp.run(['$FB', function($FB){
  $FB.init('1438666983087556');
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll keep this on my mind @apneadiving

Answer (score 2):

Thats correct I have to change my coffescript file to

```
@HomeCtrl = ['$scope', '$location', ($scope, $location) ->
    $scope.things  = ['Angular', 'Rails 4.1', 'Working', 'Together!!']
]
```

in order to make it work. Pay attention to '$scope', '$location'

Comment: Why is this needed? Why does this syntax not work: `angular.module('App').controller "CommentsFormCtrl", ($scope, $routeParams, $http, CommentService) ->`